# Timestamp returns an error on BigQuery when sent by Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send timestamp field to BigQuery from Firebase Functions.
I'm sending admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() 
and The field on BigQuery is TIMESTAMP type.

by i receive an error:

```
table.insert: {"errors":[{"errors":[{"message":"This field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}]}],"response":{"kind":"bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse","insertErrors":[{"index":0,"errors":[{"reason":"invalid","location":"datetime","debugInfo":"","message":"This field is not a record."}]}]},"message":"A failure occurred during this request."}
```

My Code is:

```
exports.sessionsToBQ = functions.firestore
  .document("/Users/{userId}/Sessions/{sessionId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

  const dataset = bigquery.dataset('App');
  const table = dataset.table('Sessions');
  tableName = 'Sessions'
  datasetName = 'App'

    dataset.exists().catch(err => {
      console.error(
        `dataset.exists: dataset ${datasetName} does not exist: ${JSON.stringify(
          err
        )}`
      )
      return err
    })

    //let table = dataset.table(tableName)
    table.exists().catch(err => {
      console.error(
        `table.exists: table ${tableName} does not exist: ${JSON.stringify(
          err
        )}`
      )
      return err
    })

    let row = {
      insertId: context.params.sessionId,
      json: {
        sessionId: context.params.sessionId,
        userId: context.params.userId,
        datetime: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        duration: change.after.data().duration,
        distance: change.after.data().distance,
        IP: change.after.data().IP
      },
    }

    return table.insert(row, { raw: true }).catch(err => {
      console.error(`table.insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
      return err
    })
  })
```

what I'm doing wrong? how to send correctly the current timestamp to big query?

Comment: If I use
Date.now() 
instead, then on big query appear
50262-12-12 00:49:52.000 UTC

Comment: It sounds like `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` doesn't return a string, it returns some kind of Object that you need to convert to a string first. Maybe consult the documentation for that method to see what it returns and how to convert it to a string representation.

Comment: if i try
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()+''
that converts it to string
i still receive an error

Comment: Yes, but what is the string? It probably isn't in timestamp format.

Comment: on Firestore it appears like that:
April 15, 2018 at 8:46:16 PM UTC+3

Comment: Right, that's not a valid timestamp from BigQuery's perspective. From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type), it should be of the form `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue resolved, By changing

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

with

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```