# Timestamp objects sent via BigQuery libraries return error "This field is not a record"

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

When sending date fields as objects to BigQuery tables that are typed as timestamps, the google java API library does not throw an exception but no data lands. Examining the "InsertAllResponse" response type returns includes the error "This field is not a record".

eg

```
Hashmap<String,Object> rowContent = new Hashmap<>();
rowContent.put("Time", new Date());
rowContent.put("Name", "Harry");
```

and then

```
BigQuery bq = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
InsertAllRequest.Builder insertReqBuilder = InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId);
insertReqBuilder.addRow({some string}, row);
InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(insertReqBuilder.build());
```

returns a response.hasErrors() true.

Also reported for [python here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2951) and [firebase here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881487/timestamp-returns-an-error-on-bigquery-when-sent-by-firebase-functions) and [javascript here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2740)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that sending dates as objects causes the client API to create a JSON record rather than a single field (and this suggests also that the datetime typing has not been explicitly mapped, so timezone issues may be introduced).

Instead, send the date/time as UTC **seconds** since 1970, ie modify the above:

```
Hashmap<String,Object> rowContent = new Hashmap<>();
rowContent.put("Time", Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000));
rowContent.put("Name", "Harry");
```

(NB: not sure how to cope with milliseconds, see eg [BigQuery not dealing with timestamp in millisecond with partition column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286217/bigquery-not-dealing-with-timestamp-in-millisecond-with-partition-column) , I'll find out and get back)

Comment: The troublesome `Date` class was supplanted years ago by one of the *java.time* classes, `Instant`. Use something like `Instant.now().getEpochSecond()` here in your code.

Comment: Yes(ish); Date is still used (there's a lot of legacy code around) and does the job in this case so it's a suitable example, and your comment is a good reminder for people to get up to date if they can.

Comment: Yes, sending date filed as Instant or as any date object, the BIG Query API constructs the date object as JSON empty object (example date_field :{}). So convert the date object as String.

Comment: @YogaGowda I have included a sample of converting the Timestamp to a string in order to get up to microsecond accuracy in my answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, BigQuery's Java API does undocumented conversion of Java types to BigQuery types. In the case of BigQuery Timestamp, the Java API converts float and int into integer truncated *seconds* since Unix Epoch. Which is pretty silly, considering almost everyone uses milliseconds since Unix Epoch and Timestamp supports up to microsecond accuracy. If you are OK with seconds, use int as seconds.

If you need more accuracy, convert your Timestamp value into a string. The canonical string according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type) is:

```
YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]
```

And here's a Java code example with 'milliseconds' storing milliseconds since Unix Epoch, but you can use whatever DateTime you might happen to have:

```
long milliseconds = 1610399564959L;
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds), ZoneOffset.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
String timestampText = dateTime.format(timestampFormatter);
rowContent.put("Time", timestampText);
```

I really wish Google would document these conversions somewhere.